# Disable right click on form field level

Tags: javascript

I am need of generic function which can disable right click on the form fields.

Comment: That's almost certainly a bad idea. Why do you want to do it?

Comment: bad...bad...bad...bad...bad...bad...bad...bad n very annoying for the user

Comment: if you are trying to "copyright" your content then be aware that the user can just look at the page source code.

Comment: By "form fields" you mean text boxes only, or other elements as well? Can we know the reason behind this?

Comment: yes only for form elements like textbox and textarea

Comment: Might be valid if you have a plugin to handle the input for a field. For example a datepicker. If disabling all input except from the datepicker we can skip frontend validation for this field and still have a consistent and reliable interface. To allow the user to circumvent this by right clicking and paste will break this and look bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
  var el = window.event.srcElement || e.target;
  var tp = el.tagName || '';
  if ( tp.toLowerCase() == 'input' || tp.toLowerCase() == 'select' || tp.toLowerCase() == 'textarea' ){
    return false;
  }
};
```

Comment: run your code in IE getting target is undefined or not an object

Comment: My bad... I tested it this time

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done - not reliably and cross-browser (FF, IE, Chrome, Opera) anyway.

There are browser-specific hacks which work in IE and FF, but there's a deeper problem: what are you trying to achieve? Limiting the user experience like this gains you nothing (they already have your precious code, else they wouldn't see the page), and annoys the users.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bad idea (annoys users because it goes against user accepted standard behavior) but you can do it in jQuery like this:

```
$(function() {
     $(this).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need an special context-menu to your form fields, you can use this JQuery plugin:

http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/contextmenu/index.php

Used like this:

```
var menu1 = [
      {
        'Option 1': function(menuItem,menu) { alert("You clicked Option 1!"); } 
      },
      {
        'Option 2': function(menuItem,menu) { alert("You clicked Option 2!"); } 
      }
];
$(function() {
  $('#myform:input').contextMenu(menu1,{theme:'vista'});
});
```

So, when the user click on any input fields of your form with id 'myform', the personal context menu will be displayed.

Comment: I don't think the OP asked for jQuery

Comment: I'm only posting another solution.