# Allowing right-click on selected class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript that prevents right click on an HTML page:

```
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

I have a `<input>` tag on that same page with the name "Link" that I want the right click to happen on.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4862354/3877877. All you need to do is check for `tp.name != 'Link'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an `if` statement inside your event listener:

```
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){
    if (e.target.name !== "Link") {
        e.preventDefault();
    }    
}, false);
```

So it basically says: when the target element does not have a name of `Link` prevent the right click.

Comment: Correct! But why would you do that?

Comment: To baypass something. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can check and test `e.target` of the event:

```
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input' && e.target.name === 'Link') {
      return; //pass
    }
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent others
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div>
   This is the Phone and NO ONE SHOULD RIGHT CLICK THIS! >:) </br>
   <img oncontextmenu="return false;" class="tlClogo" src="http://i.imgur.com/0atiS5C.jpg" style="height: 120px; width:120px;">
</div>
</br></br></br></br>
And this is the Keyboard, ofcourse yo can right click this :)</br>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/xkrKz1X.jpg" style="height: 120px; width:120px;">
```

[Working Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/q7f0gzqo/)

Comment: @SalmanA Coded as a Javascript not jquery!
anything else remaining Sir :-)
please tell me don't minus the answer sir